# Trying to grab location of job postings on website using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to grab the location tag on each job to filter them based on location as this option isn't available from
[Seek Work From Home](https://www.seek.com.au/jobs?where=Work%20from%20home) and have been using python with selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.seek.com.au/jobs?where=Work%20from%20home")
assert "SEEK" in driver.title

location = WebDriverWait(driver, 25).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,
                                                                                   '("//*[@id=""app""]/div/div'
                                                                                   '/div[4]/div/div[3]/section'
                                                                                   '/div[2]/div/div[2]/div["'''
                                                                                   '"1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/'
                                                                                   'div[2]/article/div[1]/span'
                                                                                   '[2]/span/strong/span/span"'
                                                                                   ')')))``
```

The WebDriverWait seems to timeout when trying to find the element that has the location as text (despite attempting crazy wait times)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/meagl/Desktop/Python/grabjobs/grabjobs.py", line 13, in <module>
    location = WebDriverWait(driver, 25).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,
  File "C:\Users\meagl\anaconda3\envs\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

the XPATH that I am using is the one at the very top. (Currently showing as Sydney)
What is my next step here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its look like there is issue in your xPath. As i have used below code and it printed all location for all 20 jobs on page:

```
driver.get("https://www.seek.com.au/jobs?where=Work%20from%20home")
assert "SEEK" in driver.title
location = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'location:')]")))
for loc in location:
    print(loc.text)
```

**Output**

[image]

Note : You can play with string if you just want to get city name.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever this kind of operation you are doing the locator should be selected carefully and here the xpaths used is not working. Using the xpath in the way `//*[text()='location:']` will solve your issue.